# Software to display a webpage on a screen in a public location?

Tags: browser

I would like to have a screen display a dynamic website for visitors in an elevator. Is there any open source software for doing this? Something like a welcome message, train schedule, or clock.

Comment: Would a simple PowerPoint Presentation not work?

Comment: no it should be a little dynamically ;-)

Comment: so you would like users to actually interact with the screen? In what way? You need to add info.

Comment: no interaction it's just an Information-Terminal or better screen with specific widgets like a shedule or news from CNN...

Answer (score 2):

You really need to make an effort at solving the issue yourself. You haven't shown any research or attempt at the problem.

I would however suggest you investigate the following solution:

http://www.signage.dtri.com/products/integrated_player_server_appliance/index.html

I administer the Digital Media servers for my workplace. We have about 60 micro form factor PCs streaming content from a central repository.

It's fairly easy to setup and you can get it to integrate well with AD.

## Content

Basically what you do is setup zones. Within these zones you can play/stream/display content in ANY format. So my organisation will have say:

- Zone 2: Clock
- Zone 3: Weather
- Full Screen: TV (News mainly) or Slideshows
- RSS: News feeds

You can schedule content to play at different times of the day etc etc.

## Example Zones

[image]

By no means is this a programmatic answer, though its simple and relatively low cost. If you have any questions let me know. But again I would stress the importance of providing enough USEFUL information in your question so that others can benefit in the future.

I provided this answer as opposed to code as I did not see any evidence of programming experience. If you would prefer a programmatic solution, please provide code samples and further context.